# Interpreter programming challenge

Tags: c++, performance, strings, programming-challenge, vectors

I have posted here my working and accepted solution to the intepreter programming challenge (detailed [here](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=974)) for your review. The challenge is as follows:

> A certain computer has 10 registers and 1000 words of RAM. Each register or RAM location holds a 3-digit integer between 0 and 999. Instructions are encoded as 3-digit integers and stored in RAM.
>   The encodings are as follows:
>
> - `100` means halt
> - `2dn` means set register d to n (between 0 and 9)
> - `3dn` means add n to register d
> - `4dn` means multiply register d by n
> - `5ds` means set register d to the value of register s
> - `6ds` means add the value of register s to register d
> - `7ds` means multiply register d by the value of register s
> - `8da` means set register d to the value in RAM whose address is in register a
> - `9sa` means set the value in RAM whose address is in register a to the value of register s
> - `0ds` means goto the location in register d unless register s contains 0
>
> All registers initially contain `000`. The initial content of the RAM is read from standard input. The first instruction to be executed is at RAM address 0. All results are reduced modulo 1000.
>
> **Input**
>
> The input begins with a single positive integer on a line by itself indicating the number of the cases following, each of them as described below. This line is followed by a blank line, and there is also a
>   blank line between two consecutive inputs.
>
> The input to your program consists of up to 1000 3-digit unsigned integers, representing the contents of consecutive RAM locations starting at 0. Unspecified RAM locations are initialized to 000.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, the output must follow the description below. The outputs of two consecutive cases will be separated by a blank line.
>
> The output from your program is a single integer: the number of instructions executed up to and including the *halt* instruction. You may assume that the program does halt.
>
> **SampleInput**
>
> ```
> 1
> 299
> 492
> 495
> 399
> 492
> 495
> 399
> 283
> 279
> 689
> 078
> 100
> 000
> 000
> 000
> ```
>
> **SampleOutput**
>
> ```
> 16
> ```

The program recognizes the required commands:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <fstream>

    //platform specific code. 
    #ifdef WINDOWS
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #endif

    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::vector;
    using std::getline;
    using std::string;
    using std::istringstream;
    using std::endl;
    using std::stoi;

    static void execute_case();
    static void skip_blank_lines();
    static void fill_ram();
    static void halt();
    static void set_register(int register_address, int value);
    static void increment_register(int register_address, int value);
    static void multiply_register(int register_address, int value);
    static void copy_register(int destination_address, int source_address);
    static void sum_registers(int destination_address, int value_address);
    static void multiply_registers(int destination_address, int value_address);
    static void copy_ram_to_register(int destination_register, int source_ram);
    static void set_ram(int destination_ram, int source_register);
    static void jump_to(int register_location, int register_sentinel);
    static void initialize_memory();


    int number_of_instructions = 0;
    int line_number = 0;
    const int N_RAM_WORDS = 1000; //Number of words of ram our interpretor can store. 
    const int N_REGISTERS = 10; //Number of registers. 
    const int MAX_VALUE = 1000; //All values in registers and ram must be less than this. 
    const int DEFAULT_VALUE = 0; //default values for all registers and ram words. 

    int n_cases; //The number of input cases in input
    vector<int> registers(N_RAM_WORDS, DEFAULT_VALUE); //each element registers[i] stores the value of register i.  
    vector<int> ram_words(N_REGISTERS, DEFAULT_VALUE);  // each element ram_words[i] stores the value at memory address i. 

    int main()
    {

        //first line of input is the number of cases to follow. 
        cin >> n_cases;

        // skip two lines seperating number of cases from first case. 
        skip_blank_lines();


        for (int i = n_cases; i > 0; i--) {
            execute_case();

            // print an extra blank line for all but the last case. 
            if (i > 1) {
                cout << "\n"; 
            }

        }

    }

    //this function skips two lines seperating number of cases from first case. 
    static void skip_blank_lines() {
        string input;
        getline(cin, input);
        getline(cin, input);
    }

    static void execute_case() {
        initialize_memory();
        fill_ram();
        while (line_number < 999) {
            int instruction = ram_words[line_number] / 100;
            int parameter1 = ram_words[line_number] % 100 / 10;
            int parameter2 = ram_words[line_number] % 10;
            number_of_instructions++;

            switch (instruction) {
            case 1:
                if ((parameter1 == parameter2) && (parameter1 == 0)) {
                    halt();
                    return;
                }
                break; 

            case 2:
                set_register(parameter1, parameter2);
                break; 

            case 3:
                increment_register(parameter1, parameter2);
                break; 

            case 4:
                multiply_register(parameter1, parameter2);
                break; 

            case 5:
                copy_register(parameter1, parameter2);
                break;

            case 6:
                sum_registers(parameter1, parameter2);
                break;

            case 7:
                multiply_registers(parameter1, parameter2);
                break;

            case 8:
                copy_ram_to_register(parameter1, parameter2);
                break;

            case 9:
                set_ram(parameter1, parameter2);
                break;

            case 0:
                jump_to(parameter1, parameter2);
                break;
            }

            line_number++; 
        }
    }

    //resets all registers and ram words to their default value
    // ie. 000. 
    static void initialize_memory() {
        std::fill(registers.begin(), registers.end(), 0);
        std::fill(ram_words.begin(), ram_words.end(),0);
        number_of_instructions = 0;
        line_number = 0;
    }

    //reads all instructions executed for a case from stdin. 
    //input is terminated by a blank line. 
    static void fill_ram() {

        string input_line;
        int word_number = 0;
        while (getline(cin, input_line)) {
            if (input_line.empty()) {
                return;
            }

            //convert line into an integer which is then stored in ram_words. 
            ram_words[word_number] = stoi(input_line);
            word_number++;
        }
    }

    //prints out the number of instructions executed for input case. 
    static void halt() {
        cout << number_of_instructions << "\n" ; 
    }

    //sets the register at register_address to value. 
    void set_register(int register_address, int value) {
        registers[register_address] = value%10;
    }

    //increments the register at register_address by value. 
    static void increment_register(int register_address, int value) {
        registers[register_address] = (registers[register_address]+value) % MAX_VALUE;
    }

    //multiplies the register at register_address by value.
    static void multiply_register(int register_address, int value) {
        registers[register_address] = (registers[register_address]* value) % MAX_VALUE;
    }

    //copies the register at source_address to destination_address
    static void copy_register(int destination_address, int source_address) {
        registers[destination_address] = registers[source_address];
    }

    //sums the registers at destination_address and value_address and stores the result in register destination_address
    static void sum_registers(int destination_address, int value_address) {
        registers[destination_address] = (registers[destination_address]+registers[value_address]) % MAX_VALUE;
    }

    //multiplies the registers at destination_address and value_address and stores the result in register destination_address
    static void multiply_registers(int destination_address, int value_address) {
        registers[destination_address] = (registers[destination_address]*registers[value_address])%MAX_VALUE;
    }

    //copies the value stored at ram_word number source_ram to register number destination_register
    static void copy_ram_to_register(int destination_register, int source_ram) {
        registers[destination_register] = ram_words[registers[source_ram]];
    }

    //sets the ram_word whose address is stored in register number destination ram to the value stored in register number source_register. 
    static void set_ram(int source_register, int destination_ram) {
        ram_words[registers[destination_ram]] = registers[source_register];
    }

    //if sentinel_register is not 0 it
    //jumps to and executes the instruction stored in the ram_address stored in register location_register

    static void jump_to(int location_register, int sentinel_register) {
        if (registers[sentinel_register] == 0) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            line_number = registers[location_register]-1;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Fix the bug

The code currently contains these two lines:

```
vector<int> registers(N_RAM_WORDS, DEFAULT_VALUE); 
vector<int> ram_words(N_REGISTERS, DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

However, it's obvious that `N_RAM_WORDS` and `N_REGISTERS` should be swapped.  Being able to spot such errors is one advantage to having named constants as you do.

### Eliminate global variables

In this case, eliminating global variables is easy and obvious.  As @LokiAstari advises, simply wrap everything except `n_cases` up into a nice neat `Machine` object.  Then `n_cases` can be declared within `main`.

### Make all instruction handlers alike

All instructions except for `halt` look alike.  They are each `void` functions taking two `int` arguments.  I'd suggest making `halt` look like that, too, and move the parameter checking to within the body of the `halt` function.  This makes it easier to implement the next suggestion.

### Consider making the code more data driven

Right now there is a big `switch` with each case being almost identical except for the function called.  I'd recommend instead using a table driven approach instead.  In my case, I made all instruction handlers return `bool` which indicates "halted", so only `halt()` actually returns true.  The call then looks like this (

```
if ((this->*inst[instruction])(parameter1, parameter2))
    return;
```

I've made all of the functions member functions of a `Machine` class as mentioned above.  Then there is a table that is also part of that Machine class:

```
   bool(Machine::*inst[10])(int, int) = {
            &Machine::jump_to,
            &Machine::halt,
            &Machine::set_register,
            &Machine::increment_register,
            &Machine::multiply_register,
            &Machine::copy_register,
            &Machine::sum_registers,
            &Machine::multiply_registers,
            &Machine::copy_ram_to_register,
            &Machine::set_ram,
    };
```

This is simply an array named `inst` of 10 pointers to member functions. The syntax would be similar for C-style functions except of course they would not have a `Machine::` anywhere.

### Use all required `#include`s

The code makes use of `std::string` and `std::stoi` but does not `#include <string>`.  It should.

### Use *only* required `#include`s

It doesn't appear to me that this program actually needs anything from either `<sstream>` or `<fstream>` so these two lines can safely be deleted:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
```

Answer (score 3):

Overall very good.

If you are throwing away input you can use `std::ignore()` rather than `std::getline()`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/164694/14065

I know that normally self documenting code you have a function for each action. But in this specific case I think that is overkill. That's because each function is a single line. I would just manually inline each function (that is only a single line).

I don't like your global variables:

```
    int number_of_instructions = 0;
    int line_number = 0;

    vector<int> registers(N_RAM_WORDS, DEFAULT_VALUE); //each element registers[i] stores the value of register i.  
    vector<int> ram_words(N_REGISTERS, DEFAULT_VALUE);  // each element ram_words[i] stores the value at memory address i.
```

These seem to all be part of the machine. I would wrap these in a class that represents the state of the whole machines. This can then be a single object in `main()` with all the functions becoming private methods.

My `main()` would have looked like this:

```
int main()
{
    cin >> n_cases;
    skip_blank_lines();

    for (int i = n_cases; i > 0; i--)
    {
        Machine   machine(std::cin);
        machine.execute();
        std::cout << machine.getInstructionCount() << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    while (line_number < 999)
```

is not correct. Nothing in the spec says that falling over results in termination. Instead, it says that **all** results (including the program counter) are reduced modulo 1000.

I also recommend to increment the `line_number` *before* executing an instruction (like a typical hardware does). This way the jump instruction doesn't have to subtract 1 from the `location_register`'s value.

Comment: You provide a reasonable interpretation about the program counter (that it rolls over to 0) but I'm not sure that it's necessarily incorrect to halt instead.  I'd count that more as a bug in the requirements rather than the code since it doesn't explicitly say what happens in that instance.  For that matter, it also doesn't say what should happen with a `123` instruction.  It probably shouldn't `halt`, but does it count as an instruction?  The spec doesn't say.